# Output of /proc/net/wireless shows signal level -256

Tags: linux, wifi

I am getting

```
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22
 wlan0: 0000   70.  -256.  -256        0      0      0      0      0        0
```

as output of `cat /proc/net/wireless`.

I would like to get the actual signal level in db. However the signal level seems to be invalid. What could cause the signal level to be -256 while the wifi connection and performance is perfectly fine.

Comment: What is the operating mode of the device (Ad-Hoc, Managed, Master, Repeater, Secondary, Monitor) ? if unsure about what this means, refer to https://manpages.debian.org/testing/wireless-tools/iwconfig.8.en.html under the "mode" paragraph.